# Manipulating inequalities in epsilon delta

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

I need to show that the polynomial $$x^3-x-3$$ is continuous at $x=1$ using epsilon delta proof but I'm facing some problem manipulating the inequality.

Given $$\epsilon>0$$

$$0<|x-1|<\delta$$

Continuity implies $$|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$$

so$$x^3-x-6<\epsilon$$

How do I manipulate the last line such that I have something that resembles the $$(x-1)$$?

Comment: $x^3-x-3$? Or $x^3-x-6$?

Comment: You don't want $x^3-x-6<\epsilon$, you want$$|(x^3-x-3)-(1^3-1-3)|<\epsilon\ ,$$that is, $|x^3-x|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Hi David, do you mind explaining your motivation?
Doesn't continuty implies |f(x)-f(x0)|<e?

Comment: I see I made an algebraic error!

Comment: I managed to factorise the above down to
$$|x(x+1)(x-1)|<\epsilon$$
Should I be diving $$\epsilon$$ by x(x+1)?

Answer (score 1):

If you set
$$
f(x)=x^3-x-3,
$$
then we have
$$
|f(x)-f(1)|=|x^3-x|=|x(x^2-1)|=|x(x+1)(x-1)|=|x^2+x||x-1| \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
In particular, for $0\le x \le 2$ (i.e. for $|x-1|\le 1$) we have
$$
|f(x)-f(1)|\le 6|x-1|.
$$
Therefore, given $\varepsilon>0$, if we set $\delta=\frac{1}{6}\min\{1,\varepsilon\}$, then for for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|x-1|< \delta$ we have
$$
|f(x)-f(1)|\le 6|x-1|<6\delta\le \varepsilon.
$$
Hence $f(x)=x^3-x-3$ is continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: In particular, for 0≤≤2 (i.e. for |−1|≤1), here, did you let delta=1?

Answer (score 0):

If $|x-1|\lt\delta$ we have $1-\delta\lt x\lt1+\delta$, so we have $0\lt|(x+1)x(x-1)|\lt|(2+\delta)(1+\delta)(\delta)|$, and it is easy to see that the right hand side can be made as small as we like.

Answer (score 0):

in a fairly general context:

1) a constant function is continuous

2) the identity automorphism is continuous

for maps $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ prove by an epsilon-delta argument:

3) the sum/difference of two continuous functions is continuous

4) the product of two continuous functions is continuous

now apply these four propositions to obtain: $x \to 3$ and $x \to x$ are continuous. $x \to x^2$ is continuous. $x \to x^3$ is continuous. $x \to x^3-x$ is continuous. $x \to x^3-x-3$ is continuous

Comment: That's the easy way, but it's not what the OP asked.